# How to Obtain Text Template Transformation Toolkit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I've setup a new laptop and have download (via SVN) some large projects related to my work.

I'm now getting a bunch of errors similar to the following.

> Error 5 The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Can anyone help me understand what happened? While Googling, I found several references to "Text Template Transformation Toolkit". Is that a separate download? I was not able to find it.

I just installed a fresh copy of Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: You may want to look at the [VSVMSDK](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk), it seems to have a [TextTemplating](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ttsample) sample.

Comment: T4 is installed with VS, on what file-type does it error? Most likely an incomplete/older/... version of EF or MVC or something like that. Check all packages.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: There is no filename. It simply lists the name of the project after the error message I posted above. But perhaps I need to update EF or something. I'll check that out.

Comment: T4 is included in VS PRO versions and up. However what it's looking for here are the build target file which I don't think is included. If you look at: http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/ he describes two prereqs which you might need. The SDK and the modelling and visualization kit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file referenced is the additional msbuild support for T4, which is included in the Visualization and Modeling SDK.  You'll first need the [Visual Studio 2012 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668), then the [VSVM SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30680) itself.

Comment: Is there such a SDK for VS2013?